# Flutter align a custom bottom at bottom center of screen?

Tags: flutter, button, alignment

My custom button does not align at bottom center of screen and right now my custom button is centered at bottom of container. Its only part of code below. Any ideas on how I can fix so my custom button appears at bottom center of screen?

```
  class _MainMenuState extends State<MainMenu> {

       @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Header(text: 'Home', style: Fonts.header1),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
     backgroundColor: ColorStyle.black,
      body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Util.paddingTop,
                TextFieldNormal(),
              Expanded(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: ButtonNormal(
                  text: 'Go to next screen',
                  width: width * 0.8,
                  height: 50,
                  color: ColorStyle.blueDark,
                  onPressed: () => pushNewScreen(
                    context,
                    screen: BottomNavBarWidget(
                      menuScreenContext: context,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )),
);
```

}

}

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap `BottonNormal` inside `Expanded` Widget.

```
 Expanded(
           child: Align(
             alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: ButtonNormal(
               // ... 
              ),
            ),
         ),
```

**Why it was not working:**

It is because the column takes the entire screen, but the widget renders vertically which will take their own space only.

**Solution:**

Wrap the bottom widget using the `Expanded` widget which will take the remaining space from the bottom in `Column`, so afterwords bottom alignment can work

Comment: I have updated code, but that doesn't work since I get error:                           "RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderSingleChildViewport#565f2 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1702 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
    SingleChildScrollView".

Comment: It works if I remove SingleChildScrollView. But I want to be able to use Scrollview on smaller device. How do I fix that?

Comment: You can singleChildScrollView as parent

Comment: @DavidRuland: If it works, could you accept the answer.

Comment: @DavidRuland it doesnt work I have tried it out